# componentWillReceiveProps isn't called until component is focused, is it something I've done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I have a ReactJS component that I'm developing which needs to get some information from the URL. To do this I've been utilizing the *componentWillReceiveProps* lifecycle method to look at *props.location.query* and dispatches actions to a *Redux* store in order to update the known state. The problem that I'm running into is that it doesn't appear that *componentWillReceiveProps* is being called for my component until that component has focus. I can reload the page which hosts this component and the render is called but *componentWillReceiveProps* is never called first.

Clearly I'm either understanding the lifecycle incorrectly with respect to *componentWillReceiveProps* or there is something else either wrong in my component or application which is make it behave differently than it is intended. Please set me straight either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

componentWillReceiveProps isn't called on the first render.

From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops):

"Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render."

Comment: Excellent, I knew there was something I must have been overlooking. This [discussion here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3610) also helped me come to the same conclusion. Thanks for your help!